# Remove textinput from DatePicker

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a `DatePicker` and I want to remove the possibility to input a date by typing, the reason for this is that even if I set a `DisplayDateStart` and `DisplayDayEnd` you can still get to dates outside this scope if you type them in manually instead of selecting them with the calendar GUI

Also is it possible to make only present dates selectable?

Answer (score 2):

To disable typing input you can use the same technique as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956614/wpf-datepicker) - apply style to the DatePickerTextBox class that is used by DatePicker internally

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
     <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Comment: This only works for the textbox, but not for the button nor the context menu

Comment: @DavidDiez which is what OP wanted